# There was an error installing gem gem-wrapper, rubygems-bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am trying to install ruby version 2.1.2 using rvm.

Below is the details of the same. Installation of ruby 2.1.2 through rvm is completed with following warnings.

[image]

After installation, when doing gem list getting below error.

[image]

I am pretty new to ruby on rails. Any leads on how to solve this please?

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the text into your question instead of linking images? That makes the text searchable for people who want to help you and it might help others in the future to find this question and answers too.

Comment: Check if this is possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741367/ruby-using-wrong-version-of-openssl

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby using wrong version of openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741367/ruby-using-wrong-version-of-openssl)

Comment: Sorry I could not check yesterday. I tried following the steps in the link provided. Have posted a concern in that thread when tried following the steps. Thanks @lacostenycoder!!